# I have a form modal and need to replace/hide/ toggle it upon submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

So basically I have a form modal, I need it to hide and show my second modal upon submission, without leaving the page.

This is what I'm using, I'm not great at this stuff and this is probably an easy fix.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $form = $('form');

    $form.submit(function () {
      $.post(
        $(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
          $('#myModal2').modal('show');
        },
        'json'
      );

      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: What is the issue you facing now using the above code?

Comment: Once I click submit, the action works perfectly fine but the modal does not close or toggle. 

Basically, the form action works but I want to close the form modal and open up the second modal once they click submit

Comment: Is the page reloading completely?  Try changing your submit button from `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"`

Comment: The page doesn't react, nor does the modal. It runs the action but nothing happens to the page itself.

Comment: I tried changing the button type as well, its still the same. on the front end it looks as though there has been no reaction but on the back end im receiving the form contents.